# Less organize :nth-child active states

Tags: css, less

I'm using less for this project and currently designing a navigation bar and using `:nth-child` to style the `li` elements by multiples of 3. I'm also trying to manage `active` states (shown below under `//li active states for nav` comment).

I'm trying to make any active `li` item have `background-color: white`. The solution below adds:

```
            &:nth-child(3n + 1):hover {
              background-color: white;
            }
```

to *each* of the active `:nth-child` declarations. Surely there is a way to do something like `&:nth-child(all):hover` or something that's DRYer than what I have below. See my LESS:

```
       li {
          color: white;
          padding: 0.9em;
          // nav item 1 and multiple
          &:nth-child(3n + 1) {
            border-top: 2px solid @blue;
            &:nth-child(3n + 1):hover {
              background-color: @blue;
            }
          }
          // nav item 2 and multiple
          &:nth-child(3n + 2) {
            border-top: 2px solid @red;
            &:nth-child(3n + 2):hover {
              background-color: @red;
            }
          }
          // nav item 3 and multiple
          &:nth-child(3n + 3) {
            border-top: 2px solid @green;
            &:nth-child(3n + 3):hover {
              background-color: @green;
            }
          }
        }
        // li active states for Nav
        .active {
          background-color: white;
          &:nth-child(3n + 1) {
            color: @blue;
            &:nth-child(3n + 1):hover {
              background-color: white;
            }
          }
          &:nth-child(3n + 2) {
            color: @red;
            &:nth-child(3n + 2):hover {
              background-color: white;
            }
          }
          &:nth-child(3n + 3) {
            color: @green;
            &:nth-child(3n + 3):hover {
              background-color: white;
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this ...

```
  &:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    border-top: 2px solid @blue;
    &:nth-child(3n + 1):hover {
      background-color: @blue;
    }
  }
```

... to this ...

```
  &:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    border-top: 2px solid @blue;
    &:hover {
      background-color: @blue;
    }
  }
```

Your LESS will output ...

```
li:nth-child(3n + 1):nth-child(3n + 1):hover
```

... but you want ...

```
li:nth-child(3n + 1):hover
```

Follow this pattern through all the rest of your LESS.

As for the `.active` state - `li.active` will have the same specificity as `li:nth-child(3n + 1)` etc., so simply include `li.active` after the :nth selectors.

//EDIT - final solution

```
li {
    color: white;
    padding: 0.9em;
    // nav item 1 and multiple
    &:nth-child(3n + 1) {
        border-top: 2px solid @blue;
        &:hover {
            background-color: @blue;
        }
        &.active{
            color: @blue;
        }
    }
    // nav item 2 and multiple
    &:nth-child(3n + 2) {
        border-top: 2px solid @red;
        &:hover {
            background-color: @red;
        }
        &.active{
            color: @red;
        }
    }
    // nav item 3 and multiple
    &:nth-child(3n + 3) {
        border-top: 2px solid @green;
        &:hover {
            background-color: @green;
        }
        &.active{
            color: @green;
        }
    }
    // li active states for Nav
    &.active{
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps organizationally. Any insight about applying the same :hover state to *all* of the active class items?

Comment: Sorry - see my edit ... that should sort out the second issue.